# Type convert a jQuery object back to undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, null, undefined

I have a question about jQuery. I was wondering if it's possible to `typeconvert` a jQuery-object to `undefined`.

Like this:

```
alert(typeof $mobileMenu); // Return undefined
$mobileMenu = $('<ul id="mobile-menu"></ul>'); 
alert(typeof $mobileMenu);  // Return object
$mobileMenu = null;  // Here I want it to convert back to undefined.
alert(typeof $mobileMenu);  // This returns "object" but what I want is it to return "undefined"
```

Thanks.

Comment: `null` is not `undefined`. So convert directly to `undefined` instead of `null` read here: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/understanding-undefined-and-preventing-referenceerrors/

Comment: is that work for you ..............

Answer (score 2):

```
$mobileMenu = null;
```

change to

```
$mobileMenu = undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

if want that than you need to do this

```
$mobileMenu= undefined;
```

**null** - It generally makes sense and behaves similarly to other scripting languages' concepts of the out-of-band ‘null’, ‘nil’ or ‘None’ objects.

so setting `null` doesnt make any sense if you want `undefined`.

**Note:** The strict equality operator rather than the standard equality operator must be used here, because x == undefined also checks whether x is null, while strict equality doesn't. null is not equivalent to undefined.